# Moduli space of instantons on non-compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory

Are there any references about the moduli space of instantons on a general non-compact manifold?

Comment: Yes. Or no. If you want a better responce, ask a better question. http://math.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any work on Donaldson theory on general non-compact manifolds, but if you assume the manifold is nicely behaved "at infinity," there are some references:

- [*$L^2$ Moduli Spaces on 4-Manifolds with Cylindrical Ends*](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/books/_home/_default/index.php/Mono-GeometryTopology-L2ModuliSpaces-v1.php), Clifford Taubes, International Press, ISBN: 1-57146-007-1.
- [*Gauge theory on asymptotically periodic $4$-manifolds*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-25/issue-3/Gauge-theory-on-asymptotically-periodic-4-manifolds/10.4310/jdg/1214440981.full), Clifford Taubes, J. Differential Geom. Volume 25, Number 3 (1987), 363-430.
- [*ASD moduli spaces over four-manifolds with tree-like ends*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405443), Tsuyoshi Kato, Geom. Topol. 8(2004) 779-830, arXiv:math/0405443v1 [math.GT].

The special restriction on the asymptotic behavior of the manifold is apparent in the title of each respective work; see the references for precise definitions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. These are exactly the kind of stuff  I was looking for.

Comment: Four years later, but: Morgan-Mrowka-Ruberman is also worth noting; more or less an alternate approach to the ideas in Taubes' book.